# When requesting post, there is no content in the request header body

Tags: html

```
<body>
    <form action="/signup" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        ID : <input type="text" name="signupID" id="signupID">
        PW : <input type="text" name="signupPW" id = "signupPW">
        <input type = "submit" value="signup">
    </form>
</body>
```

And I entered the value
I've seen request, but I can not find the value anywhere
Where is the value I entered?

request: POST /signup HTTP/1.1
request: Host: localhost:8080
request: Connection: keep-alive
request: Content-Length: 38
request: Cache-Control: max-age=0
request: Origin: http://localhost:8080
request: Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
request: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
request: Content-Type: text/plain
request: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
request: Referer: http://localhost:8080/
request: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
request: Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Comment: you should be able to see it on the server side

Comment: A web server created in Java receives the request. What should I do?

Comment: It looks like you are on local so I assume you know how the server side of things work. You should be able to find the coming request and see the stuff you sent.